# create Ethernet static IP on artik10

Tags: networking, fedora, ethernet

I can't seem to fix my Ethernet IP on my artik10.
I followed the instructions on the ARTIK documentation as followed:

changed /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
into:

```
DEVICE="eth0"
TYPE="Ethernet"
ONBOOT="yes"
BOOTPROTO="static"
USERCTL="no"
IPADDR=192.168.10.199
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
BROADCAST=192.168.10.255
NETWORK=192.168.10.0
GATEWAY=192.168.10.1
```

and add to the /etc/resolv.conf file the following:

```
nameserver 192.168.1.1
```

but the eth0 IP doesn't change on reboot
it does change on

```
systemctl restart network.service
```

but I don't want to be needed to do that every time.

Comment: Use `systemctl enable network.service` to start a service on boot.

Answer (score 0):

The Linux Kernel does not restore interface configurations by it's own. So, after a reboot, the IP address, the address of the gateway etc. is gone. Most Linux distributions use some sort of software, that starts on boot and configures the interfaces. This can be NetworkManager, systemd's networkd, a DHCP client or, like in your case, the network service.

The network service is started by systemd, either manually using `systemctl start network` or automatically after each reboot using `systemctl enable network`. You can also use `systemctl enable network && systemctl start network` to have a configured network interface from now on :)